# Moving Text Fields during input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have set up some text fields and labels to look like a simple form which will have to get some user input. My problem is however that whenever some of the text fields are selected and the keyboard slides out, the text fields are covered making it impossible to see the input. My question is how can I move up the text fields so that they stay in view when selected. Maybe someone who is more experienced can help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good solution for this which I like to do is listen to when the textfield begins editing with the following delegate function:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //keep a member variable to store where the textField started
    _yPositionStore = textField.frame.origin.y;

    //If we begin editing on the text field we need to move it up to make sure we can still
    //see it when the keyboard is visible.
    //
    //I am adding an animation to make this look better
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate Text Field Up" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    commentTextField.frame = CGRectMake(commentTextField.frame.origin.x,
                        160 , //this is just a number to put it above the keyboard
                        commentTextField.frame.size.width,
                        commentTextField.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and then in this callback you can return it to its original location:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animate Text Field Up" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    commentTextField.frame = CGRectMake(commentTextField.frame.origin.x,
                        _yPositionStore ,
                        commentTextField.frame.size.width,
                        commentTextField.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}

You will need to declare _yPositionStore as a member variable of CGFloat and have your textFields delegate be set to the view controller that owns it(either using Interface builder and dragging delegate to files owner or setting yourTextField.delegate = self)

I hope that helps

Comment: This actually helped quite a bit. I forgot to set the text field delegates. Only thing I need to fix now is dismissing the keyboard once the user presses the done button on the keyboard. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: When app is resumed from background its view frame will be wrong

Answer (score 2):

Do do this you need to follow next 2 steps:
- put all your `UITextViews` into `UIScrollView`
- register for keyboard notifications and slide your `UIScrollView` when keyboard appears
Both steps explained here: ["Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7)

Comment: Cool, thank you for showing me this link. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can call delegate methods of UITextfield and customize it according to requirement.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];

}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];

}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 110; 
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; 

    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"aimation" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    yourView.frame= CGRectOffset(yourView.frame,0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my applications I use the following code assuming that keyboardHeight is 216 for portrait and 162 for landscape mode:

```
#pragma mark - textField delegate

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // keyboard is visible, move views
    CGRect myScreenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    int keyboardHeight = 216;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    int needToMove = 0;
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    if (textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height > (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight)) {
        needToMove = (textField.frame.origin.y + textField.frame.size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height) - (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight);
    }
    frame.origin.y =  -needToMove;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // resign first responder, hide keyboard, move views
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This formula takes into account the status bar, navigation bar and display size. And of course do not forget to set the delegate for your fields.

And with:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
}
```

you can hide the keyboard, when the user tap outside the field.